# Directly calling url with Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

If I navigate to a view by clicking on a link such as `127.0.0.1/#/project/1`, the correct view gets displayed. However, if I call this url directly in the browser (or hit refresh), the view won't be displayed. What could be the reason for this behaviour?

The way I set up the Router is as follows:

```
var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
      routes: { },
      initialize:function () { }
});
var app = new AppRouter();
```

and then in every module (I'm using require.js), a route and handler will be added

```
app.route("project/:id", "showProject");
```

Could it be that the routes aren't registered yet and thus the callbacks won't be called?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure that you are calling `Backbone.history.start()` after all of your routers are loaded/instantiated and routes defined: http://backbonejs.org/#History-start

Alternatively, you could stop the history with `Backbone.history.stop()`,  and start it again. Then the added route(s) will be picked up.

BTW, you can test if the history is currently started with the boolean `Backbone.History.started` (note the capital 'H' is necessary).

Comment: I found out what it was when debugging `Backbone.history.start()`. I had this method called in `$(document).ready(function() { Backbone.history.start(); }`, which was located in one of the requirejs modules. I wasn't aware that this is already getting called when the module finished loading, as opposed to when all modules are being loaded. Thanks anyway. Your comment helped to look at the right place.